# CURLpp: TLS Handshake Error

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, curlpp

This question is similar to another [one, concerning pyCURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942719/pycurl-tls-handshake-error)

I have the following error when I send a post request to a secure url, using CURLpp `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942719/pycurl-tls-handshake-error`

Ok, so according to the answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942719/pycurl-tls-handshake-error), I should use libcurl with openSSL. If I run `curl -v`, I get this:

`curl 7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz`

So I should be using openSSL, and not see gnuTLS. So if I try to send the very same request through curl directly with the command line, it works fine, and I see on the command output the result I am expecting.

So It turns out when I switch to CURLpp, it uses gnuTLS, instead of openSSL. 
Is there something I have to configure, in order to specify I want openSSL with CURLpp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURLpp is just a wrapper over libcURL, it doesn't dictate which SSL implementation libcURL uses.
Am not exactly sure how you've come to the `when I switch to CURLpp, it uses gnuTLS, instead of openSSL` conclusion but I suspect that you have multiple libcurl.so installed, the one curl uses and another that your app is using (via cURLpp).

As a side note, the `TLS fatal alert ... received` (mentioned in the linked question) was probably a result of a misconfiguration on the **server side** (invalid servername TLS extension, failure to negotiate ciphers, etc).

Comment: Indeed, I have `libcurl-gnutls.so    libcurl-gnutls.so.4.1.1 ` installed. I need to find out how I get CURLpp not to use them.

Comment: I have installed libcurl4-openssl-dev, and reinstalled curlpp, I don't have the error anymore. Thanks